# ScatterView, Touch mouvement, label mouvement win8

Tags: c#, touch, windows-8, scatterview

I'm on Win8 and I would like to move a label with fingers ( rotation, zoom , mouvement)

I saw that i can do it with a scatterview but, this control seems to be hard to use...
I'd like to know if you know other control which can help me doing this ?

A Sample of ScatterView ?

win8 dont got that kind of control ?
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a Canvas, and use the [OnManipulationDelta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmanipulationdelta.aspx) events on each control.

I have done this in CP, but I haven't tried it in release preview.